# Evaluate $\displaystyle\int\frac{\arcsin e^x}{e^x}\,dx$.

Tags: calculus, analysis

> Evaluate 
>   $$
> \int\frac{\arcsin e^x}{e^x}\,dx.
> $$

What I got is 
$$
\int -\arcsin e^x\,de^{-x}=-\arcsin e^x\cdot e^{-x}+\int\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}}\,dx
$$

Comment: Note that with the substitution $e^x \mapsto u$ the integral is reduced to $\int \frac{\arcsin\left(u\right)}{u^2}$ and you can easly solve it with the subtisution $u \mapsto \sin\left(x\right)$ after performing integration by parts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
I=\int -\arcsin e^x\,de^{-x}=-\arcsin e^x\cdot e^{-x}+\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}}
$$

Then, let $t=e^{-x}$ to integrate,
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}}=-\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}=-\text{arccosh}\> t +C$$

Thus,

$$
I=-e^{-x}\arcsin e^x-\text{arccosh}\> e^{-x}+C$$

Comment: I think $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}}$ should be $\int\frac{dx}{e^x\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}}$.

Comment: @Xie - Note that $(\arcsin e^x)'=\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}}$ and $e^x$ cancels out.

Comment: Oh, yes, my fault.

Comment: That first step is integration by parts right?

Comment: @gen-z ready to perish - correct, the step that OP takes.